# ParseQueryException: Bad protocol (Android SDK)

Tags: android, performance, parse-platform

I'm using Parse's Android SDK as my back-end, and sometimes the queries are taking a very long time, even when using my 100Mb WiFi connection, and even though I only have less than 10 Users and 30 records in all the Parse classes combined.

Sometimes I get the list (after a long time of waiting), but sometimes the error i receive is "ParseQueryException: Bad protocol"

Maybe my queries are to blame. Here's an example of a (usually) slow query, trying to find all my user's roommates, meaning, all the OTHER users who's HOME COLUMN points on the same home as the logged user:

```
ParseObject home = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Homes",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseObject("home").getObjectId());
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ShoppingItems");
query.whereEqualTo("home", home);
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
     public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
          pd.dismiss();
          if (e == null) {
               parseList = results;
               recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), parseList));
          } else {
               Log.d("LIST ERROR", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: I see no reason for such a query to take longer than others. Only wondering why you don't simply do `query.whereEqualTo("home", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseObject("home"));`

Comment: Also `query.orderByDescending("createdAt");` should be the default behavior, so might as well be omitted

Comment: I see no reason too, yet it happens so I have no idea what's causing it. Sometimes the query takes a milisecond, 5 seconds later it could take 9-10 seconds!

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm experiencing extremely slow query times when doing "saveall" queries with Parse SDK (iOS)